# Corrupt iesysprep.dll in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, malware, dll

While trying to figure out if I have a malware problem on Windows 7 Pro, I did a `sfc /scannow` in both Safe Mode and from a recovery disk, but both times the shell responded *Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.*

Looking at my log, it appears the only broken file is `iesysprep.dll`:

`00000385 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:48{24},l:46{23}]"\??\C:\windows\SysWOW64"\[l:26{13}]"iesysprep.dll"; source file in store is also corrupted`

Googling this tells me that it has something to do with Internet Explorer. So I have two questions about this:

1) I'm concerned that this file is infected by malware. Is there any way to restore it without a full reinstall, seeing as how I wasn't able to from the recovery disk?

2) If the answer to the above is negative, can I go to Windows Features -> "Turn Windows features on or off" and disable Internet Explorer 11 (which I don't care about since I exclusively use Firefox and Chromium)? Will that neutralize any possible malware resulting from this?

Comment: You will have to use a Windows 7 installation, along with the SFC command, in order to repair the corruption.

Comment: You can disable IE if you want, but if the file is malware, it won't be removed from your system if you do that.

Comment: `sfc /scanfile=d:\windows\SysWOW64\iesysprep.dll/offbootdir=d:\ /offwindir=d:\windows` Within WinRE run this command from a command prompt.

Comment: [You should also scan all your system files](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-sfc-offline-windows-7-vista/), so use, `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=d:\  /offwindir=d:\windows` to acomplish that.

Comment: I did that from the recovery disk. I got the same error as described above.

Comment: You used a Recovery Disk or an Installation Disk?

Comment: Recovery, which the OEM shipped with the computer I bought.

Comment: The OEM recovery disk isn't what you need.  Download a Windows 7 ISO for the same version you have installed, boot to it, then run those commmands.  Alternatively you can run those commands from within Windows, and provide the mounted .ISO, as the source to repair the file also..

Comment: I was under the impression that OEM copies of Windows 7 aren't available for download, hence why I used the recovery disk. Microsoft's website doesn't accept my OEM activation key in order to access the ISOs in any case.

Comment: Your impression is wrong.   There is an existing question, with a answer that I wrote, that explains how to download a Windows 7 .ISO

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your error is due to your permission modifications from default settings, by some means.

Try Solution 2  (no brainer)

This occurs error because the relevant Sysprep registry entries point to the wrong location, for iesysprep.dll, after installing IE10.

1) System Restore or follow MS solution

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2868126

2) download and run exe  http://www.sysnative.com/niemiro/apps/SFCFix.exe  from desktop And upload result text file.  ( time ~10 minutes)
ref: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/584893/file-corruption-cwindowssyswow64iesysprepdll/

Comment: Thank you for that. I've concluded that this probably isn't malware but a common bug that Microsoft hasn't fixed.

Comment: @lightspectra - The article doesn't cover your corrupt system file.  The errors described in the article are different.  **You have system corruption, which you should fix, at your earliest convenience.**

Comment: @Ramhound please provide details on what you suggest.

Comment: @TonyStewart - The article you linked to does not apply to his problem.  The user has IE11 installed not IE10.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I'm concerned that this file is infected by malware. Is there any
>   way to restore it without a full reinstall, seeing as how I wasn't
>   able to from the recovery disk?

Yes, though this is a very late answer, but hopefully still useful. I saw a similar error following an `sfc /scannow` run and analysis of the CBS.Log. For me the file was different, and I also suspected malware however it seemed that it was genuinely corrupted.

I downloaded a "clean" version of the file from pconlife.com which hosts multiple versions of your file:

http://www.pconlife.com/viewfileinfo/iesysprep-dll/

In order to replace your corrupt file, you may need to take ownership of it first, then you can overwrite it with the downloaded one:

```
takeown /f d:\windows\SysWOW64\iesysprep.dll

icacls d:\windows\SysWOW64\iesysprep.dll /Grant Administrators:F

copy {your-file-path}\iesysprep.dll d:\windows\SysWOW64\iesysprep.dll
```

All of these steps resolved my corrupt file, and finally I used sfc again to check the new file:

```
sfc /verifyfile=d:\windows\SysWOW64\iesysprep.dll
```